# What's the equivalent of Wevtutil in XP or 2003?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, batch, event-log

I have a batch file for saving event logs to our shared drive. I want to do this for XP and Server 2003 without very much effort. What could I use since Wevtutil is only on Vista and up?

```
rem Script start here
rem Timestamp Generator

set BACKUP_PATH=\\shared-drive\it\Temp\Event-Logs\

rem Parse the date (e.g., Thu 02/28/2013)
set cur_yyyy=%date:~10,4%
set cur_mm=%date:~4,2%
set cur_dd=%date:~7,2%

rem Parse the time (e.g., 11:20:56.39)
set cur_hh=%time:~0,2%
if %cur_hh% lss 10 (set cur_hh=0%time:~1,1%)
set cur_nn=%time:~3,2%
set cur_ss=%time:~6,2%
set cur_ms=%time:~9,2%

rem Set the timestamp format
set timestamp=%cur_yyyy%%cur_mm%%cur_dd%-%cur_hh%%cur_nn%%cur_ss%%cur_ms%

rem Set the computername format
set servname=%computername%

wevtutil epl System %BACKUP_PATH%\%servname%_%timestamp%_system.evtx
wevtutil epl Application %BACKUP_PATH%\%servname%_%timestamp%_application.evtx
wevtutil epl Security %BACKUP_PATH%\%servname%_%timestamp%_security.evtx

rem End of Script
```

Comment: `C:\> eventcreate /?`

Comment: The command 'wevtutil epl ...' creates a copy of the logfile.  The original poster is not asking how to add a log entry, but rather how to grab a copy of the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

Use Logevent.exe:

```
logevent "This is a test"
logevent -m \\server1 -s W -c 100 -r "my batch program" -e 88 "batch program failed!"
```

> In Windows 2003, XP, and Win2K, you can create, manage, and report on ETW sessions two ways: You can use the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Performance Logs and Alerts snap-in, or you can use command-line utilities. In Windows 2003 and XP, the OS includes the command-line utilities. In Win2K, the command-line utilities are part of the Microsoft Windows 2000 Server Resource Kit and differ slightly from those in Windows 2003 and XP. In the context of the ETW architecture, the Performance Logs and Alerts snap-in and some of the command-line utilities are controller applications. Other command-line utilities provide the consumer application function.

Use one of the following tools for trace logging:

```
 logman 
 tracelog
```

**References**

- [How to Use Logevent.exe to Log Events From a Batch File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131008)
- [How To Use the Event Logging Utility (Logevent.exe) to Create and Log Custom Events in Event Viewer in Windows 2000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315410)
- [How to create custom events](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324145)
- [Inside Event Tracing for Windows](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/inside-event-tracing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you are asking for can be done directly.  The closest I've been able to get is to use wmic to dump the records.  That method proved to be unreliable for me in Windows 7, but it seemed to work under Windows XP.

Example snippet:

```
    Rem The first time that WMIC runs, it may output "Please wait while WMIC is being installed." followed by the unicode answer.
    Rem cmd /a /c does not work correctly with a mix of single and double byte chars in the file.   So run first command twice (or ignore the problem).
    wmic os get lastbootuptime > %LogFileJunk%
    wmic os get lastbootuptime > %LogFileJunk%

    Rem Following call can be followed by SQL-like filters such as: GET * /format:csv OR GET TimeGenerated,User /format:csv
    wmic NTEVENT WHERE "LogFile='security' AND TimeGenerated > %Recent%" list /format:htable > %LogFileJunk% 2>nul
    dir %LogFileJunk% > NUL
    for %%c in (%LogFileJunk%) do if %%~zc GTR 2 GOTO GotLog1
    Echo !!!Unable to retrieve!!! >> %LogFileTmp%
    GOTO DoneLog1
    :GotLog1
    cmd /a /c type %LogFileJunk% >> %LogFileTmp%
```

Note the workarounds for wmic:

- Run it twice in case there is a helpful (ANSI) message the first time
- Check to make sure a real file (> 2 characters) was created
- In my case, I needed to translate from unicode to ANSI (the 'type' command)